# GStreamer Distortion only on some PNG Files

Tags: c, gstreamer

I’m building a streaming server where gstreamer renders image frames in sequence. Some png images are rendered fine and others don't render (black screen is shown in the autovideosink) and the pipeline crashes at the end with a segfault.

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 imagesequencesrc location="testImage%d.png" start-index=0 stop-index=4 framerate=1/1 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Got context from element 'autovideosink0': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayCocoa\)\ gldisplaycocoa0";
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
Redistribute latency...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
Execution ended after 0:00:05.005155000
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
Caught SIGSEGV
```

Interestingly, images that are opened in Preview on Mac and then re-saved always work fine even when their original format caused the crash. When these images are passed through alone the pipeline succeeds without any errors. My best guess is there's something corrupted about these image files but I'm unsure about how to diagnose what's causing the issue.

Interestingly, repainting these problematic images to a smaller size in Go with the following code *does not* help the issue. We still see the crash.

```
    paths := [...]string{"testImage0.png", "testImage1.png"}
    for index, element := range paths {

        file, err := os.Open(element)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        img, _, err := image.Decode(bufio.NewReader(file))
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        // Get the size of the
        bounds := img.Bounds()
        w := bounds.Dx()
        h := bounds.Dy()

        fmt.Printf("width: %d, height: %d\n", w, h)

        output, _ := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("testResized%d.png", index))
        defer output.Close()

        // Set the expected size that you want:
        dst := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, img.Bounds().Max.X/2, img.Bounds().Max.Y/2))

        // Resize:
        draw.NearestNeighbor.Scale(dst, dst.Rect, img, img.Bounds(), draw.Over, nil)

        // Encode to `output`:
        png.Encode(output, dst)
    }
```

Normal & corrupted image data is available here for reference: https://filetransfer.io/data-package/KW2yDoO6#link. The corrupted data appears in `testImage1.png`.

Comment: What GStreamer version? The pipeline works fine for me on Linux with 1.22.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch 1.22.0 on OSX - maybe a mac specific issue?

Comment: 1.22 via brew or official GStreamer release? But yeah, could be a bug. If you can do a stack trace of the crash people may have an idea what may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're 'streaming' chunks of data which represent an image. That is one picture frame of which 25 (or whatever) make one second of video. If the data chunk is out of synch between the recieved image and the time it takes to process and display it you will get a partial or boken image. This possibly happens because the two devices are not sending and recieving and processig the image (frame) at the exact same rates. You could reduce frame rates to reduce the processor overhead and thus reduce the data load.

Comment: @winson - I don't think this is what's wrong. My set framerate in the gstreamer is 1 frame per second, and only the corrupted image doesn't show. The rest show fine. I'm also testing on a localhost connection so packet speeds of this magnitude shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Hi. It is possible that you can configure your logging and then examine the log files for more info in whats happening. I must admit I'm not an expert so I don't want to send you in any wrong direction. I did find this link related to your question which may interest you : https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/issues/281  --- it may not be exact to your requirements but the comments on the article seem to offer some insight.